# how to remove new line added in every html page,ajax response ..?

Tags: html

In every HTML page/Ajax response at the beginning,  two new blank line is added automatically.

It may be virus but didn't find  any kind of unwanted line/code in js or other file which can give me idea of how this two new blank line is added.

It added at top of any html page/ajax response.

If anyone has idea how to detect and remove ??

Comment: Hah, yeah, virus. You've probably got leading/trailing whitespace in one of your files

Comment: Please provide more information about your question: what is generating the HTML? What technology are you using? Does it happen during only certain requests? Files?

Comment: hi,i m using PHP and it is added in every page html,any ajax response..in every request ..in jquery ajax response new line is not appended to response from server side but when i check length in js,it is appended at the beginning of any response ..and in html before this line <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC  .....two new line is added ...how can i find and remove that ?